# Excel 2007 - Worksheet is larger than the window

Tags: excel-2007, ms-office

This is an odd problem but frustrating none the less.

I have a worksheet saved which is larger than the Excel 2007 "workarea".

This means when I open the worksheet I cannot access the corners of the worksheet to reduce the size and the worksheets title bar area (with move,size,minimise etc) is hidden beneath the ribbon , even if I remove the ribbon , I still can't see the title bar.

In Excel 2003 I've had a similar effect but I've always been able to hit the "alt" key to access the "Move" option.

However in Excel 2007 , hitting "alt" brings up some shortcuts for the ribbon etc but I can't access the worksheet options.

Has anyone else know how to access the worksheet drop down when this happens?

Comment: You'll probably have more and better answers on SuperUser.com - this is definitely not a programming-related question and therefore doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 1):

`View` -> `Arrange All` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely in your monitor setup in Windows. Maybe have a play around with that so that Maximized windows don't maximize to a size greater than your screen size.